# Load a file that stored inside a jar file

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I have a FXML file in my project at myproject/fxml/myScreen.fxml and I try to load it with FXMLLoader:

```
content.getChildren().setAll(FXMLLoader.load(new URL("myproject/fxml/myScreen.fxml")));
```

But then I get this exception,

```
`java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: myproject/fxml/myScreen.fxml`
```

Can someone show me where were I wrong ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Let your ClassLoader load it as a resource (assuming the jar is on your classpath / using the same classloader as your current class) and provide it as stream:

```
content.getChildren().setAll(FXMLLoader.load(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("myproject/fxml/myScreen.fxml")));
```

Comment: I have this problem when following your instruction Description Resource Path Location Type
Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method load(InputStream) from the type FXMLLoader

Comment: Use `getResource(...)`, not `getResourceAsStream(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an error because you haven't defined the **protocol** in the parameter passed to the `URL()`.

It generally accepts a `HTTP/File` address. If you want to load a file, you are expected to add `file:` prefix in your string.

Th correct way to load a file which exist in your local machine you can use :

```
FXMLLoader.load(new URL("file://myproject/fxml/myScreen.fxml"));
```

**Best Way**

To load a file which exists in your jar, the best way is to use `getClass.getResource(PATH_TO_FXML)` in [FXMLLoader.load()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html#load-java.net.URL-)

Since you are directly loading the fxml and assigning it to the content, you must use the non-static [load()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html#load--) of the FXMLLoader.

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/myproject/fxml/myScreen.fxml"));
content.getChildren().setAll(loader.load());
```

Comment: Hi i tried with your suggestion to load a file which exists in the jar, but i have this exception javafx.fxml.LoadException: No resources specified.
file:/C:/Users/win/myApplication.jar!/myproject/fxml/myScreen.fxml

Comment: Hi, I still have the same problem :(

Comment: this FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/myproject/fxml/myScreen.fxml"));
content.getChildren().setAll(loader.load());

Comment: I think (though I'm not certain), that "no resources specified" means you are trying to access a resource bundle in the FXML (e.g. `<Label text="%myText"/>`) and you haven't set the resource bundle on the `FXMLLoader`.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Oracle documentation: 
[Example](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/FXMLExample.java.html)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Application.launch(FXMLExample.class, args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("fxml_example.fxml"));

    stage.setTitle("FXML Welcome");
    stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
    stage.show();
}
```